# What is the correct way to handle a POST request in Django class based view?

Tags: json, django, post, get

In my class based view I am handling a post request (which is an AJAX call).I am inserting some data in a database table and returning some json to the frontend.

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

    result_data = {}
    doc = kwargs['doc']
    doc_obj = Document.objects.get_document(doc)

    doc_id = doc_obj.doc_id
    reference_obj = Reference.objects.save_to_db(request,doc_id)

    friendly_name = reference_obj.friendly_name
    result_data['friendly_name'] = friendly_name

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result_data),content_type='application/json')
```

My question is that is this the right way of handling a post request?My doubt arises here - I am writing some data into database and returning a json of properties of the same data I have written to the database.

Should I do it differently, ie first storing some data in database and returning just id of the row and again making GET request on the same URL?

Answer (score 0):

I would say if it is an API, it is best to minimize the number of queries by returning the whole object the way you did. In case it is to serve a web user interface, it is simpler to return the id and get the rest of the data, if it needs to be displayed, from the client itself.

Either way is fine. The gain is negligible. I have also seen applications give a local positive feedback and then replace with a negative one if the request was unsuccessful. The technique can improve responsiveness, which is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Django-rest-framework returns the json of the inserted object, so i would think it reasonable to copy that behaviour.